# Reading and taking specific file contents in a list in python

Tags: python

I have a file containing:

```
name: Sam
placing: 2
quote: I'll win.

name: Jamie
placing: 1
quote: Be the best.
```

and I want to read the file through python and append specific contents into a list. I want my first list to contain:

```
rank = [['Sam', 2],['Jamie', 1]]
```

and second list to contain:

```
quo = ['I'll win','Be the best']
```

first off, i start reading the file by:

```
def read_file():
    filename = open("player.txt","r")
    playerFile = filename
    player = []   #first list
    quo = []   #second list

    for line in playerFile:   #going through each line 
        line = line.strip().split(':')  #strip new line 
        print(line) #checking purpose
        player.append(line[1])     #index out of range
        player.append(line[2])
        quo.append(line[3])
```

I'm getting an index out of range in the first append. I have split by ':' but I can't seem to access it.

Comment: Strings without the delimiter result in a 1-list.

Comment: what is the format of the file: is it always three lines or are entries separated by an empty line ?

Comment: @zython yes it's always three lines. Three lines for first record, three lines for second record.

Answer (score 0):

When you do **line = line.strip().split(':')** when **line = "name: Sam"** 
you will receive **['name', ' Sam']** so first append should work.

The second one player.append(line[2] will not work.

As zython said in the comments , you need to know the format of the file and each blank line or other changes in the file , can make you script to fail.

You should analyze the file differently:
If you can rely on the fact that "name" and "quote" are always existing fields in each player data , you should look for this field names.

for example:

```
for line in file:
# Run on each line and insert to player list only the lines with "name" in it
    if ("name" in line):
    # Line with "name" was found - do what you need with it
    player.append(line.split(":")[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

A few problems,

- The program attempts to read three lines worth of data in a single iteration of the `for` loop.  But that won't work, because the loop, and the `split` command are parsing only a single line per iteration.  It will take three loop iterations to read a single entry from your file.
- The program needs handling for blank lines.  Generally, when reading files like this, you probably want a lot of error handling, the data is usually not formatted perfectly.  My suggestion is to check for blank lines, where `line` has only a single value which is an empty string.  When you see that, ignore the line.
- The program needs to collect the first and second lines of each entry, and put those into a temporary array, then append the temporary array to `player`.  So you'll need to declare that temporary array above, populate first with the `name` field, next with the `placing` field, and finally append it to `player`.
- Zero-based indexing.  Remember that the first item of an array is `list[0]`, not `list[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
def read_file():
    filename = open("player.txt", "r")
    playerFile = filename
    player = []
    rank = []
    quo = []

    for line in playerFile:
        value = line.strip().split(": ")
        if "name" in line:
            player.append(value[1])
        if "placing" in line:
            player.append(value[1])
        if "quote" in line:
            quo.append(value[1])
            rank.append(player)
            player = []

    print(rank)
    print(quo)    

read_file()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused on how to check for a line and add content from line to two lists based on what it contains. You could use `in` to check what line you are on currently. This works assuming your text file is same as given in question.

```
rank, quo = [], []
for line in playerFile: 
    splitted = line.split(": ")
    if "name" in line:
        name = splitted[1]
    elif "placing" in line:
        rank.append([name, splitted[1]])
    elif "quote" in line:
        quo.append(splitted[1])

print(rank)  # [['Sam', '2'],['Jamie', '1']]
print(quo)   # ["I'll win",'Be the best']
```